# Editor that shows RegEx selection and replacement results?

Tags: text-editor, html-editor, regex, editor

Doing a lot of regular expression search and replacements can be a hassle sometimes.  I've found that a tool on macOS called "Better Rename" does a fantastic at showing a preview / live view of what is selected and then the result of the replacement:
[image: alt]

Is there an editor on macOS that gives a similar style of having multiple panes to show the regex matches and the resultant replacements that will be made?

So far the closest thing I've found so far is in `Sublime Text` where it gives a preview of the selection of a regex, but not the change / replace function...

Answer (score 2):

I use this: [RegExRX](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/regexrx/id498370702?ls=1&mt=12)

And since a picture is worth a 2<sup>10</sup> words, so:

[image: Search]
[image: Replace]

Comment: I like the visual clarity of this. I sure do wish it was in the actual text editor that's editing the file though vs having to paste in sample text.

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case in text editing, <strike>The One True Editor</strike> Emacs has a package for doing this. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38110451/2636454) about doing the very same thing in Emacs. Here are links to the relevant packages:

- https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el
- https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el

The second one allows usage of regexp engines other than Emacs' own regexp engine, which has some differences when compared to, for example, PCRE. To install these packages, [add the MELPA package repository to your `package-archives` variable](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MELPA) (in [Spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/) this is done by default), then do `M-x package-install visual-regexp` & `M-x package-install visual-regexp-steroids`.

Comment: That's really slick. A screencast of this setup and usage with key presses would be fantastic. I wish it was a little more visual in the sense of seeing a columnar view like a diff; left: original+match and right: resultant output of replacement; both colorized for visual clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every JetBrain product does have a live preview (grey box)

[image]

Of course there is (as you mentioned) SublimeText

If you can live without a graphical user interface you can use [`sed`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html)

Comment: Huh, that's really interesting. It might even be better to show it in reverse, but this is quite nice.

Comment: I did not do this since you were only talking about GUI's in your question ;)